# grouping based on non-identical line items xsl1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

I have requirement as below to implement transformation using only XSL1.0,

1. First condition is Group line items based on **parentLineNumber**.
2. Then the second condition is to ignore the invoice line when **ParentLinenumber** and **LineNumber** is same when only if group has more than one invoice line item.

**Sample Input:**

```
<InvoiceNotification>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000010</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK06</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000011</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK07</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000012</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK08</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000020</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000020</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>GK01</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
    </Invoice>
</InvoiceNotification>
```

I have developed below XSLT which is partially working.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Invoices" match="InvoiceLineItem" use="LineSection/parentLineNumber"/>
    <xsl:template match="InvoiceNotification">
        <Invoices>
            <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceLineItem [ count ( key('Invoices',LineSection/parentLineNumber)[1] | . ) = 1 ]">
                <Batchorder>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('Invoices',LineNumber)">
                        <Items>
                            <LineItem>
                                <xsl:value-of select="proprietaryInformation"/>
                            </LineItem>
                        </Items>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Batchorder>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Invoices>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Resulted output:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoices>
    <Batchorder>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>PK06</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>PK07</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>PK08</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
    </Batchorder>
    <Batchorder>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>GK01</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
    </Batchorder>
</Invoices>
```

But I am **expecting below output**,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoices>
    <Batchorder>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>PK07</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>PK08</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
    </Batchorder>
    <Batchorder>
        <Items>
            <proprietaryInformation>GK01</proprietaryInformation>
        </Items>
    </Batchorder>
</Invoices>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same solution as the one proposed by Martin Honnen, but **probably a little bit more efficient**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Invoices" match="InvoiceLineItem" use="LineSection/parentLineNumber"/>
    <xsl:template match="InvoiceNotification">
        <Invoices>
            <xsl:for-each select=
            "Invoice/InvoiceLineItem
            [count ( key('Invoices',LineSection/parentLineNumber)[1] | . ) = 1]">
                <Batchorder>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('Invoices',LineNumber)
                    [not(LineNumber = LineSection/parentLineNumber)
                    or not(key('Invoices',LineNumber)[2])]">
                        <Items>
                            <LineItem>
                                <xsl:value-of select="proprietaryInformation"/>
                            </LineItem>
                        </Items>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Batchorder>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Invoices>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<InvoiceNotification>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000010</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK06</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000011</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK07</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000010</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000012</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>PK08</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
        <InvoiceLineItem>
            <LineSection>
                <parentLineNumber>000020</parentLineNumber>
            </LineSection>
            <LineNumber>000020</LineNumber>
            <proprietaryInformation>
                <FreeFormText>GK01</FreeFormText>
            </proprietaryInformation>
        </InvoiceLineItem>
    </Invoice>
</InvoiceNotification>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Invoices>
   <Batchorder>
      <Items>
         <LineItem>
                PK07
            </LineItem>
      </Items>
      <Items>
         <LineItem>
                PK08
            </LineItem>
      </Items>
   </Batchorder>
   <Batchorder>
      <Items>
         <LineItem>
                GK01
            </LineItem>
      </Items>
   </Batchorder>
</Invoices>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, yes this works as expected . Thanks for your time to help here !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate on the `for-each` I think:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('Invoices',LineNumber)[LineNumber != LineSection/parentLineNumber or count(key('Invoices', LineNumber)) = 1]">
```

Comment: I don't think this can work without applying a similar predicate to the key. But I did not fully understand OP's requirement, so I could be wrong.